# Android: fragment restore after screen orientation change

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm starting with fragments and I'm facing a problem. I wan't to restore my fragment after a screen rotation.
My app looks like this: on landscape I have a button on the left area, which updates the a label on the right area. If on portrait mode, I'm navigating to a new activity. However, I wan't to maintain the fragment state after rotating.
Code looks like this:

Left area fragment:

```
public class ListFragment extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list, container, false);
    Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button.setOnClickListener(this);

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch (v.getId()) {

    case R.id.button1:
        updateDetail();
        break;

    }
}

public void updateDetail() {
    String newTime = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis());
    DetailFragment fragment = (DetailFragment) getFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.detailFragment);
    if (fragment != null && fragment.isInLayout()) {
        fragment.setText(newTime);
    } else {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                DetailActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("value", newTime);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

}

Right area activity:

```
public class DetailActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        finish();
        return;
    }       

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            String s = extras.getString("value");
            TextView view = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.detailsText);
            view.setText(s);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Right area fragment:

```
public class DetailFragment extends Fragment {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRetainInstance(true);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater
            .inflate(R.layout.fragment_detail, container, false);

    return view;
}

public void setText(String item) {
    TextView view = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.detailsText);
    view.setText(item);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();

    DetailFragment fragment = (DetailFragment)fm.findFragmentById(R.id.detailFragment);

    if (fragment == null) {
        fragment = new DetailFragment();
        fragment.setTargetFragment(this, 0);
        fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.detailFragment, fragment).commit();
    } 
}
```

}

What can I possibly be doing wrong?

Comment: Can you tell is what is happening and what you expect to happen, You haven't really asked a question :)

Answer (score -1):

You have a few options you can use the Bundle in a [couple](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onCreate%28android.os.Bundle%29) of methods to [save](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle)) and [restore](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onViewStateRestored%28android.os.Bundle%29) the state of the fragments.

Or you can possibly use the [setRetainInstance](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setRetainInstance%28boolean%29) method:

```
onCreate(Bundle save)
{
   super.onCreate(save);
   setRetainInstance(true);
}
```

Keep in mind that the setRetainInstance method doesn't work for fragments in the backstack.

Answer (score -2):

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    int orientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
    switch (orientation) {
    case Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE:
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.detailFragment, new DetailFragment()).commitAllowingStateLoss();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(new DetailFragment()).commitAllowingStateLoss();
        break;
    case Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT:
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.detailFragment, new DetailFragment()).commitAllowingStateLoss();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(new DetailFragment()).commitAllowingStateLoss();
        break;
    }
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

You can check on the `onConfigurationChange` and ensure that your fragment state is not lost by doing a `commitAllowingStateLoss`

Comment: `commitAllowingStateLoss()` does not ensure that the fragment state is not loss. In fact, it does quite the opposite: it *allows* the fragment's state to be lost. See this [**blog post**](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/08/fragment-transaction-commit-state-loss.html) for more information.

Comment: Also, this is not a good solution because it requires setting `configChanges` in the manifest and that is generally bad practice (unless you are up for handling all configuration changes yourself manually using pure java code).